# Angular in Chrome sublink

Tags: angular, apache, https

Iam testing my Angular website and have the problem that I cant reach sublinks.

e.g.

https://testing.my-site.de
-works.
-Click on a link to "/main" works too and leads me there.

But calling directly:
https://testing.my-site.de/main
gives me a 404.

Is it a Webserver/https settings I miss?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Gregor

Comment: Read this : https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting Angular inside Web API for example you'll need to do something like this in your Startup.cs to change request to index.html when using routing.

Same principle would apply elsewhere I guess.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
           app.UseDefaultFiles();

            app.UseMvc();

            app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
            {
                builder.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");
                    return next();
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apache redirect calls (/*) to index.html. If you have some api eg. /api just exclude it.